# Best way to add a calendar to a textbox

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm pretty new to XAML/C# and have a view that contains two textboxes.  When the user clicks on the textbox, I want it to open up a basic calendar with either today's date or the date of the textbox.  Once the date has been clicked, I want it to return that value.

I was going to create a new XAML view with a calendar control and then work it with variables, but before I did that I wanted to know if there is a better / more technically correct way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are developing WPF application then just use DatePicker control and if you want to get time also then install Extended WPF Toolkit in that use the DateTimePicker Control...

Developing for Windows Phone or WinRT (Windows Store) apps use DatePicker Control.

Comment: That makes more sense - thank you for the quick response (greatly appreciated).